# Why doesn't this code with a function pointers compile?

Tags: c++, qt, function, pointers

I want to pass a function pointer as argument.

Class definition header

```
class Networking : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Networking(QObject *parent = 0);
    QNetworkAccessManager* manager;

private:
    QUrl buildCall(QString method, QMap<QString, QString> parameters);

public slots:
    void reply(QNetworkReply* reply, void(*ptr)(const void *)); // error here
};
```

In class source

```
Networking::Networking(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    this->manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
}
void Networking::reply(QNetworkReply* reply, void(*ptr)(const void *)) // error here
{
    //some code
}
```

Compiling gets an error:
Parse error at "void"

Command:

```
/usr/lib/qt/bin/moc -DQT_WEBKITWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/home/dev/cpp/net-client -I/usr/include/qt -I/usr/include/qt/QtWebKitWidgets -I/usr/include/qt/QtWebKit -I/usr/include/qt/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt/QtCore -I. -I/usr/include/c++/4.9.1 -I/usr/include/c++/4.9.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/c++/4.9.1/backward -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include-fixed -I/usr/include ../project/Networking.h -o moc_apihandler.cpp
```

I tried to use, but received same error

```
typedef void (*ptr)(const void*);
```

Comment: Use a `typedef` to define the signature...

Comment: The problem can be earlier in the code: please post earlier lines also, along with the information on which line the error is reported.

Comment: It's a good syntax ([demo](http://ideone.com/zXwqrR)).

Comment: Still everything looks allright. The problem can be inside some headers you include. Try removing them one by one - adding fake declarations of things you use from them.

Comment: What's before the `void::Networking` ??

Comment: `public slots:` Doesn't look like C++ to me. Can't you abstract away the Qt extension?

Comment: Thanks **BartoszKP**. But how i can pass pointer to slots ?

Comment: Your error is in moc phase, if I correctly understand the sentence `Command /usr/lib/qt/bin/moc ...` The command compiles a .h file. How can the error be in *source* file ?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : The error is being issued by the Qt moc tool not the C++ compiler, so the Qt syntax is valid.  The question is not very clear on that point and perhaps should be.

Comment: @Clifford: It ---needs--- needed retagging in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/moc.html) says:

> Function Pointers Cannot Be Signal or Slot Parameters

The suggested workaround is to use a `typedef` or function objects - your own hierarchy, or [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) / [`boost::function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/function.html) if you can.

Comment: Since a typedef is simply an alias for some existing type, would a typedef solve the problem?  It is still a function pointer - or is it just the syntax moc can't handle?

Comment: @Clifford The latter, AFAIR. moc needs to parse the types of arguments to match signal calls to slots - they are further processed as strings.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are issuing is not C++ compilation but the Qt meta-object compiler(moc). moc is a preprocessor that translates Qt C++ extensions into plain C++ for compilation proper.

The error message indicates that `void` was not expected, and assuming that it refers to the function return type and is nothing to to with the function pointer, the error most likely is in the preceding immediately line or statement (whitespace and comments excluded) - more context is required to see exactly what.  If the preceeding line is an include file, then you need to be looking at the end of the included file.  Common errors are missing semi-colons and missing newline at the end of included files.